# Why the CUDA memory is not release with torch.cuda.empty_cache()

Tags: pytorch

On my Windows 10, if I directly create a GPU tensor, I can successfully release its memory.

```
import torch
a = torch.zeros(300000000, dtype=torch.int8, device='cuda')
del a
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

But if I create a normal tensor and convert it to GPU tensor, I can no longer release its memory.

```
import torch
a = torch.zeros(300000000, dtype=torch.int8)
a.cuda()
del a
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in Ubuntu, your script does not release memory when it is run in the interactive shell and works as expected when running as a script. I think there are some reference issues in the in-place call. The following will work in both the interactive shell and as a script.

```py
import torch
a = torch.zeros(300000000, dtype=torch.int8)
a = a.cuda()
del a
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Answer (score 3):

To add up to the excellent answer from @wstcegg, what worked for me to clean my GPU cache on Ubuntu (did not work under windows) was using:

```
import gc
import torch
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

You might also want to delete the elements you have created, see [How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python)

For more details about garbage collection, see this good reference, which I am quoting the interesting part hereinafter

https://stackabuse.com/basics-of-memory-management-in-python/

> Why Perform Manual Garbage Collection?
>
> We know that the Python interpreter keeps a track of references to
> objects used in a program. In earlier versions of Python (until
> version 1.6), the Python interpreter used only the reference counting
> mechanism to handle memory. When the reference count drops to zero,
> the Python interpreter automatically frees the memory. This classical
> reference counting mechanism is very effective, except that it fails
> to work when the program has reference cycles. A reference cycle
> happens if one or more objects are referenced each other, and hence
> the reference count never reaches zero.
>
> Let's consider an example.
>
> ```
> >>> def create_cycle():
> ...     list = [8, 9, 10]
> ...     list.append(list)
> ...     return list
> ... 
> >>> create_cycle()
> [8, 9, 10, [...]]
> ```
>
> The above code creates a reference cycle, where the object list refers
> to itself. Hence, the memory for the object list will not be freed
> automatically when the function returns. The reference cycle problem
> can't be solved by reference counting. However, this reference cycle
> problem can be solved by change the behavior of the garbage collector
> in your Python application.
>
> To do so, we can use the `gc.collect()` function of the `gc` module.
>
> ```
> import gc
> n = gc.collect()
> print("Number of unreachable objects collected by GC:", n)
> ```
>
> The `gc.collect()` returns the number of objects it has collected and
> de-allocated.
>
> There are two ways to perform manual garbage collection: time-based or
> event-based garbage collection.
>
> Time-based garbage collection is pretty simple: the `gc.collect()`
> function is called after a fixed time interval.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this also happens on my pc with following configurations:

- 20.04.1-Ubuntu
- 1.7.1+cu110

According to information from fastai discussion:https://forums.fast.ai/t/gpu-memory-not-being-freed-after-training-is-over/10265/8

This is related to the python garbage collector in ipython environment.

```py
def pretty_size(size):
    """Pretty prints a torch.Size object"""
    assert(isinstance(size, torch.Size))
    return " × ".join(map(str, size))

def dump_tensors(gpu_only=True):
    """Prints a list of the Tensors being tracked by the garbage collector."""
    import gc
    total_size = 0
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        try:
            if torch.is_tensor(obj):
                if not gpu_only or obj.is_cuda:
                    print("%s:%s%s %s" % (type(obj).__name__, 
                                          " GPU" if obj.is_cuda else "",
                                          " pinned" if obj.is_pinned else "",
                                          pretty_size(obj.size())))
                    total_size += obj.numel()
            elif hasattr(obj, "data") and torch.is_tensor(obj.data):
                if not gpu_only or obj.is_cuda:
                    print("%s → %s:%s%s%s%s %s" % (type(obj).__name__, 
                                                   type(obj.data).__name__, 
                                                   " GPU" if obj.is_cuda else "",
                                                   " pinned" if obj.data.is_pinned else "",
                                                   " grad" if obj.requires_grad else "", 
                                                   " volatile" if obj.volatile else "",
                                                   pretty_size(obj.data.size())))
                    total_size += obj.data.numel()
        except Exception as e:
            pass        
    print("Total size:", total_size)
```

if I do something like

```py
import torch as th
a = th.randn(10, 1000, 1000)
aa = a.cuda()
del aa
th.cuda.empty_cache()
```

you will not see any decrease in nvidia-smi/nvtop.
But you can find out what is happening using handy function

```py
dump_tensors()
```

and you may observe following informations:

```sh
Tensor: GPU pinned 10 × 1000 × 1000
Total size: 10000000
```

That means your gc still holds the resources.

One may refer to more discussions for python gc mechanism.

1. [Force garbage collection in Python to free memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167386/force-garbage-collection-in-python-to-free-memory)

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same issue.
Solution:

```
cuda = torch.device('cuda')
a.to(cuda)
```

Answer (score -2):

You should not use `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` as it it will slow down your code for no gain https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-torch-cuda-empty-cache-do-and-where-should-i-add-it/40975

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. people generally do it for testing on smaller GPUs.